# saving a camera taken picture in sdcard in phonegap app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using the [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) camera API to take a picture. After taking the picture, it will be displayed in my page. It works, but pictures are saved in the application cache folder,

`/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/mypackage.com/cache`.

Instead, I want to save them in a folder in my SD card, `/mnt/sdcard/myFolder`, or something like that. I have gone through lot of Q&A, but I couldn't find the way I want.

Here is my source code.

```
  <html>
     <div data-role="page" id="camera_page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Camera-page</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <button onclick="capturePhotoWithData();" data-theme="a">Capture Photo</button> <br>

            <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
            <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">footer</div>
</div>

</html>

//here is my  java script

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var pictureSource;   // picture source
  var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

  // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
   //
   document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

 // PhoneGap is ready to be used!
  //
 function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
  // Get image handle
  console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoWithData() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

function capturePhotoWithFile() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoFileSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert("you didn't take any pictures");
}
```

Comment: did you solved it? If yes then can i Know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an OnActivityResult method checking for the correct result ID,

```
String out = "/mnt/sdcard/myFolder/mypic.png";
Bitmap b = i.getExtras().getData("data");

//Create an OutputStream, can't remember how I did it.  this.getOutputStream() maybe?

Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.valueOf(out), 100, outputStream);
```

I've done this in a project at work, I may be able to update you exactly how tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try this one. Update me when your are done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy your file to the destination, where you want it stored.

What I did, was:

- receive the fileUri from the camera.getPictures function

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(
        onSuccess,
        onFail, {
          quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI //FILE_URI!
        });

      function onSuccess(imageURI) {
        alert(imageURI); //displays the current location of the file 
        $scope.imageURI = imageURI;
      }
```

- move the file from the source folder (according to fileUri) to the destination:

```js
moveFile($scope.imageURI);

        function moveFile(fileUri) {
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
            fileUri,
            function(fileEntry){
              window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory, //insert your destination here
                function(dirEntry) {
                  // move the file to a new directory and rename it
                  fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, fileEntry.name, onSuccess(fileEntry, dirEntry), onFail);
                },
                onFail);
            },
            onFail);
        }
```

(got this mostly from [Cordova Move File using the file url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910783/cordova-move-file-using-the-file-url))

Your destination folder should be cordova.file.externalRootDirectory (according to https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).