# Cordova Move File using the file url

Tags: javascript, cordova, html5-filesystem

How can I move a file using the URL I get from the Camera?

neither successCallback nor errorCallback is called by the function moveTo. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what a possible solution looks like?

```
function successCallback(entry) {
    console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
    alert("Success. New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("Error:" + error.code)
    alert(error.code);
}

// fileUri = file:///emu/0/android/cache/something.jpg
function moveFile(fileUri) {
    newFileUri  = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "images/";
    oldFileUri  = fileUri;
    fileExt     = "." + oldFileUri.split('.').pop();

    newFileName = guid("car") + fileExt;

    // move the file to a new directory and rename it
    fileUri.moveTo(cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName, successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

I am using Cordova version 4.1.2 Also installed the Cordova File Plugin

Comment: Have you checked if you have errors in the console?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're trying to call the function moveTo on a String.

**moveTO** is not a function of String but of fileEntry. So first thing you need to do is get a fileEntry from your URI.

For that you'll call **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL** :

```
function moveFile(fileUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
          fileUri,
          function(fileEntry){
                newFileUri  = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "images/";
                oldFileUri  = fileUri;
                fileExt     = "." + oldFileUri.split('.').pop();

                newFileName = guid("car") + fileExt;
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(newFileUri,
                        function(dirEntry) {
                            // move the file to a new directory and rename it
                            fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, newFileName, successCallback, errorCallback);
                        },
                        errorCallback);
          },
          errorCallback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your solution, but like before the moveTo isn't doing anything. I already tried a similar solution same result. No callbacks or alerts in the successCallback and errorCallback.

Comment: Hi, quickfix I get the following message, fileEntry is also a object now. processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "parent" of Entry.moveTo: Expected Object, but got String.

Comment: Yes sorry I focussed at the begining of your code and did not pay attention to the end. The first argument of moveTo must also be an Entry object and not a String. So you need to once again call resolveLocalFileSystemURL to convert the String path to an Entry object. Please check my edit.

Comment: Im working with mp4 files, it worked for me, but the file is still showing up at the original dir and when i click on the mp4 file (using my android device) it shows an error, when i try to delete it it shows another error saying i cant delete the file, any idea?