# Ionic 3 - Native File issues

Tags: android, file, cordova, ionic-framework, native

I can’t seem to find any info on the error I’m getting when trying to copy a file taken with the camera to data storage. Here is my function (which is pretty much what everyone seems to do):

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

// stuff here

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private StorageProvider: StorageProvider, public viewCtrl: ViewController, private camera: Camera, public platform: Platform, private file: File{

}

// other stuff here

copyFileToLocalDir() {

  let d = new Date();
  let n = d.getTime();
  let newFileName =  n + ".jpg";
  console.log('new name',newFileName);

  this.file.copyFile(this.imagePath, this.imageName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName)
    .then(success => {
      this.lastImage = newFileName;
    }, error => {
      console.log('error saving');
    });
}
```

the line causing the error is: **this.file.copyFile(...**

The error I’m getting when running in either in emulator or on device is:
**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Invalid action**

Ionic Info:

```
cli packages: (/Users/billb/dev/customer-mkt-app/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.0
    ios-sim           : 5.0.10
    Node              : v7.8.0
    npm               : 4.6.1
    OS                : macOS Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Any thoughts on why? This function **copyFileToLocalDir()** is pretty much taken from a couple of examples for the File plugin, including from the plugin writers.

Comment: Do you use the most recent version of ionic-native? the `copyFile` method is only available in ionic-native and is then forwarded to some other method of the "real" cordova-file plugin. Maybe the plugin was changed and ionic-native has not been updated. Just a guess :)

Comment: Yes, it's the most recent. The Ionic page for the File shows copyFile on it

Comment: Have you logged the parameters of the function call before calling it? Especially `cordova.file.dataDirectory` seems a bit off.

Comment: I had logged some of them, but I've tried so many different alterations, I don't recall. Let me do that again and see what I've got.

Comment: yep, all the parameters look correct

Comment: OK I did a bit of digging and as far as I can see the "Invalid action" error is returned by cordova if the `execute` method of the plugin returns false. So the most reasonable explation is that the ionic-native wrapper is calling an action that does not exist. You could verify this by trying to use the plugin without ionic-native and then directly accessing the `copyTo` method.

Comment: Thanks @David, I'll look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from David's comments above which prompted me to dig further and better understand what File plugin is doing. And thanks to the answers on these two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536303/cannot-read-a-file-using-cordova-file-plugin-in-an-ionic-2-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910783/cordova-move-file-using-the-file-url), I finally figured this thing out. Here's my final code:

```
copyFileToLocalDir() {
let d = new Date();
let n = d.getTime();
let newFileName =  n + ".jpg";
// cordova.file.dataDirectory
let externalStoragePath: string =  cordova.file.dataDirectory;

this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.imagePath + this.imageName)
  .then((entry: any)=>{
    console.log('entry',entry);

    this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(externalStoragePath)
      .then((dirEntry: any)=>{

        entry.copyTo(dirEntry, newFileName, this.successCopy, this.failCopy);

      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      });

  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

You have to create 2 objects, one of the current file (**entry**) and one for the path to copy the file to (**dirEntry**). That was the key to working this out.

Comment: would you  please tell me from where these this.successCopy and this.failCopy are comming

Comment: well, trying to remember from 2 1/2 years ago, i'm going to take a guess that they are part of the file object. i'd have to go back and dig through all this code and try to remember what we did here.

Comment: Hey Bill..Thank you for replay My issue was solved by your solution i have just removed  this.successCopy and this.failCopy and the code is working fine. Thank you Again   